# как вызвать строки в другом методе? Чтобы не копипейстить

Tags: java

```
public void addDistance(int additinalDistance) {
    distance += additinalDistance;
    distanceOnService += additinalDistance;
}

public void addDistance(double additinalDistance) {
    

    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так будет правильнее, ибо `int` всегда без потери можно преобразовать в `double`.

```java
public void addDistance(int additinalDistance) {
   addDistance((double) additinalDistance);
}

public void addDistance(double additinalDistance) {
    distance += additinalDistance;
    distanceOnService += additinalDistance;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)